# How to get value of selected option with php

Tags: php

I have a select tag in html(not in a form). I want get value of selected option with php without submit any forms.
with jquery it is simple:

```
$("select[name='select']").change(function(){
  value = this.value;
});
```

but in php, this is not simple without submit a form. Because php is a server side language, this is imposible to use jquery variable as a php variable.
Has this a solution?

Comment: Yes, there is a solution: send the bloody data to the server, so PHP can process it. Ajax doesn't require you to submit the form

Comment: why not, you can send it via AJAX (use jquery Ajax).

Comment: If you do not submit it to the server in some way php will not know about it! php runs on the server and it is not psychic

Comment: $.ajax <-- google it  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @Anigel It... isn't? Where is that P standing for then?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select[name='select']").change(function(){
  value = $(this).val();
    $.post("ajax.php", {value: value}, function(result){
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

Then in PHP

```
<?PHP
if(isset($_POST["value"])){
    echo $_POST["value"];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is serverside. This means, after the user recieved the HTML page, it's not possible to make changes via PHP. You'll need to use jQuery.ajax to do that.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. And it's incorrect at that: you don't _need_ to use `jQuery.ajax` to perform an ajax call. There's nothing you can't do without jQ.

Comment: i didn't have the neccessary points to do a comment, but you are ofc right. also jQ isn't neded....but it's often the easiest way...

Answer (score 0):

Use [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to send your variable to a php file :

```
$("select[name='select']").change(function(){
  value = this.value;
  $.ajax({
    url: 'test.php',
    data: {myVar:value}
  }).done(function() {
    alert('done');
  });
});
```